# is amd graphics supports ubuntu 16.04 now

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

I am very new to ubuntu.
Ubuntu 16.04LTS Release on 21 April 2016. i read post on http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04. i said that ubuntu 16.04 does not support AMD GPU.

i want to know that the problem is solve by now or not ?

(todays date 23 June 2016)
currently i am using ubuntu 15.10 but it Supported until July 2016.

i don't want to format again and again.
i want permanent OS for my work.

what should i do ?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 _does_ support AMD GPUs, but only the open source drivers, which work well for most things

Comment: Be aware that support for hybrid AMD/Intel graphics are very lacking.  The system will use the Intel card but keep the AMD card powered on causing unnecessary heat and power usage. You must run certain commands to kill the card but that leads to other problems and errors, especially with suspend/resume delays.  14.04 still uses proper dynamic control which powers down the AMD card automatically.

Answer (score 0):

AMD GPUs generally work fine with the open source drivers. I'm currently using an AMD R9 Nano on 16.04 with no problems. However, I am not doing any work that requires OpenCL 2.0, nor have any apps or games which require OpenGL > 4.1.

AMD has released a beta proprietary driver for Vulkan, if you require that. If you require OpenCL 2.0 or OpenGL > 4.1, and you currently use either of those on your card, you should stay on 14.04 or 15.10 for now, with the proprietary fglrx drivers.